# What does "bolt-on" mean in this Arrow Electronics' job posting?

Tags: terminology

I came across of Arrow Electronics [job posting](https://arrow.wd1.myworkdayjobs.com/en-US/AC/job/Reading/Account-Manager_R242-1), and wondering what term "bolt-on" means. While I can find generic description of this term, I can not understand how it relates to the electronics and duties of the job holder. I found subsection "[bolt-on (chassis)](https://www.digikey.ca/catalog/en/search?filters=22728)" at Digikey website, does this "bolt-on" have any relation to electronics / component product line being sold? Or it is a property of the candidate they are looking for? Please advise.

> CLEAR CATEGORY: Sales w/ Sales **bolt-on’s**

...

> Manage all resources to grow the business with Field Application Engineers, Field Marketing, Asset, Business Process Excellence (BPE), Assignees, customers, suppliers (**bolt-on for CE**), Customer satisfaction (**bolt-on for SE**)

...

> Support the company credit policy (**bolt-on** for SE)

**Update:** if you have an urge to press close question button, consider this before doing so  -

1. This question, while is not about electrons, chip and op-amps, is about entity, playing role in EE and which has, most probably, influence on you and your life;
2. This question is NOT about job, but about *probably* industry-specific term;
3. Prove that this term *bolt-on* has no specific meaning in EE / electronics manufacturing / electronics business. I have never seen this term before anywhere, and I am not a native English speaker;
4. Last, but now least. Think about your fellow EE colleagues who may be also looking at such masterpieces from Arrow. By closing this question, thus not allowing giving (more) answers and replies to it, you may give disservice to them.

I am waiting for answer from the agency, it seems they will refer to Arrow's HR (*the only* contact for them), as they appeared also not having idea what it is.

**Update** (as a response to Jeanne): let me explain the history of why I asked this question. I have got JD from agency, and the target job is located in the country with English being non-primary language, while used to be taught in the schools. The link to JD in UK I posted in the question above is reference for you how it looks like in my JD (mine is not online). I have classical British business education, but this "bolt-on" got me stuck, and stuck just at the top of the document.

My first thought was that it is sales of something relating to bolts or bolting. So the first link to the heat sinks and product lines related to parts being bolted. **This was the time I decided to ask this question.**

Next thought was about "bolt-on" as idiom, meaning "additional". If considering JD this way, I would say it is about sales person sitting on at least 3 chairs (self, some SE and some CE), which is business nonsense, and must have been explained differently.

As I did not see this idiom anywhere else, I still think it has to do with business Arrow Electronics is in, or to culture of this company in particular.

And by the way, there're some idioms even Brits and native English speakers are not able to get without solid context.

**Update:** it seems we have a consensus here that "bolt-on" is not related to EE (product line, some specific EE business term or business technique). Let me get response from the agency (if they will ever provide one).

**Final update**: agency got stuck, and they did not go to Arrow for clarification. Both answers should be correct ones, and the best reply is by @JRaefield (below the question, he did not make it an answer). Thus I choose @pipe answer as best one (he has answered first and has the lowest score at the time of assignment).

Thanks everyone for the participation, and my apologies for being EE off-topic.

Comment: What did Arrow Electronics say when you asked for clarification?

Comment: That feels like some kind of HR jargon. I don't think it's specific to electrical engineering.

Comment: I did not ask them and agency so far. I am more than sure agency also has no idea about it (I will ask), but if I do not know this term I have no luck getting in touch with Arrow's HR for clarification.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is totally NOT about EE.

Comment: @Andyaka I am voting NOT to vote without a good reason. If you know, as a native English speaker, what *bolt-on* means in this context, please explain. The question has relation to EE for at least one reason - it is about Arrow Electronics which is in EE business, and *bolt-on* may have specific business meaning in the EE context - I never seen this before in any other business contexts.

Comment: It means *"The people writing our job descriptions aren't that smart.  They use private jargon without even realizing that's what it is or don't consider the context of those reading what they write.  You'll be working with the same kind of morons that can't write comprehensible questions on EE.SE."* If only we could downvote and close their job description!

Comment: Just from the way they use it it's clear that it is a business or sales related term, not particularly related to electronics.

Comment: None of the above. This is the communication department's equivalent of "FixMe: insert additional content for x" - in other words, **this ad was posted in unfinished form**.  However, of more issue on this site is that such a question is off-topic.

Comment: @Anonymous no, no one can tell you what they mean by that bizarreness except the job poster themselves. It's nothing to do with EE.

Comment: "Bolt-on" in this context is a sales tool related meaning. This is a sales position that, although they WANT someone with an EE and experience in electronics, is still primarily sales related, not engineering related. "Bolt-Ons" in the modern sales game are referring to aps that will be expected to be used by the sales person in the field that take the place of what used to be an "inside sales support staff" that would take care of tracking orders, monitoring credit lines, contact resource management etc. etc. Basically they are saying you're going to be on your own with an iPad and some aps.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not that I'm qualified to answer this, but my assumption when reading the description is that the responsibilities are those typical for *sales*, but with additional responsibilities *bolted-on*.

That is, you'll have to do a little bit more than just typical sales-things. What is bolted-on to this role is specified later on, such as *Customer satisfaction* and *Support the company credit policy*.

Answer (score 5):

According to the following sources and the description you gave, I think it means "(optional) extra", or "additional".

- [bolt-on (Cambridge dictionary)](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/bolt-on)
- [bolt-on (Wordreference)](http://www.wordreference.com/enit/bolt-on)

I'm not an English native speaker either, but I'm with Olin Lathrop in that they are using a confusing language/jargon just because they think the ads will seem cooler.

IMO, wankwords category!

Comment: @OlinLathrop Thanks! :-) That's useful end expressive English I learned by watching EEVBlog's Dave Jones and his commentaries about silly management and HR and Marketing departments!

Comment: @OlinLathrop And sadly I've had my share of those here in Italy! We also have many colorful expressions for that, but I will abstain, since it would be much more, ...ahem..., "not politically correct" :-D